# Having trouble updating the object property using Object.assign() - angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write results from my elastic search to a CSV file,

//result = [{"name":xyz, "state":['TX','MD'], "full_address":[{"address":"first address", "phone":"111-111-1111"},{"address":"second address", "phone":"999-999-99999"}]}

code snippet:

```
 output = [] // goes to myfile
   for (let item of results) {
       let row = Object.assign({}, item );  // make a copy
       row['state'] = provider['state'].join(", ")
 
       for (let address of item ['full_address']) {
          console.info("ADDRESS", address)  // I see it is looping through addresses
          Object.assign(row, address);
          console.info("ROW", row)  // 'address' and 'phone' property not updated
          output.push(row);
         }
         delete row['full_address'];
        }
```

I'm expecting the output:

```
name| state | address | phone
xyz | TX,MD | first address | 111-111-1111
xyz | TX,MD | second address | 999-999-99999
```

instead I'm getting:

```
name| state | address | phone
xyz | TX,MD | first address | 111-111-1111
xyz | TX,MD | first address | 111-111-1111    -->  Object.assign(row, address); is not updating the 'address' and 'phone' property of the 'row ' object
```

Can some one help me with this?

I tried

```
  let row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item ));
  row.address = address['address'];
  row.phone = address['phone'];

  Object.assign(row, address, {address:address['address'], phone:address['phone']});
```

nothing seems to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider coding more purely. Meaning not to have an object you mutate to the result you need, but instead create a new object without mutating the results item:

```js
const output = result.map(({ name, state, full_address }) => {
  return full_address.map((address) => ({
    name,
    state: state.join(", "),
    address
  }));
}).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []); // flatten the resulting arrays
```

https://codepen.io/casaper/pen/ZEObxXw?editors=0011